# Open with Explorer Button is Enabled but not responding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, open-with-explorer

SharePoint on Premise 2016
IE 11

I realize that this question is all over the internet, but I have yet to find a solution that fixes our issue. The button is not greyed out, I have it enabled, it just does absolutely nothing when you click it (No error, nothing).

I have:

- Added desktop experience feature in server manager
- Restarted the web client service on client computer and server
- Added to local trusted intranet sites
- Used 32 bit internet explorer

Still, I click the button "Open with Explorer", and nothing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you face this issue with all libraries in the site?

Comment: @M.Qassas - Yes, every single one of them.

Comment: what's the SharePoint version? what's the IE version?  Could you try to create a new empty one and check the result?

Comment: I had similar issue, but in my case only I had this problem and my colleagues could open it.

Comment: @M.Qassas - IE 11, Sharepoint 2016 On-premise

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could switch to other computer to check if the same issue will occur.

And switch to other browser to check if the same issue will occur.

Switch to other web application to check if the same issue will occur.

And then reset IE. Go to IE->internet options->advanced tab->reset.

Comment: Thank you for all of these suggestions, but still no luck!